# Is it possible to embed images in exported html

Tags: java, dynamic-reports

I'm trying to use the `JasperHtmlExporterBuilder` to generate an HTML version of a report that has images.  The two options that I seem to have are:

1. Use `JasperHtmlExporterBuilder` and `.setImagesURI("image?image=");` This method relies on the code living in some kind of web container (like tomcat) and generates IMG tags to grab images from the server.
2. Use `setOutputImagesToDir` option of `JasperHtmlExporterBuilder` and force the images to be outputted separately to a local directory on disk.

I was wondering whether there might be a 3rd option where the images are base64 encoded and put directly into the HTML that's generated.

This would be ideal for me as I'd really like to return one complete result that's entirely self-contained.

<strike>One way I can "hack" it would be to use option #2 from above, then iterate over the images that get outputted, read them in, convert to base64 and manually replace the `src` part of the generated HTML.</strike>

**Update:** Below is my actual implementation based on the "hack" I describe above. Would be nice to do this better - but the code below is doing what I need (thought not very memory friendly).

```
public String toHtmlString() throws IOException, DRException {
    File tempFile = Files.createTempFile("tempInvoiceHTML", "").toFile();

    Path tempDir = Files.createTempDirectory("");

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    JasperHtmlExporterBuilder htmlExporter = export.htmlExporter(fileOutputStream).setImagesURI("");

    htmlExporter.setOutputImagesToDir(true);
    htmlExporter.setImagesDirName(tempDir.toUri().getPath());
    htmlExporter.setUsingImagesToAlign(false);

    reportBuilder.toHtml(htmlExporter);

    String html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(tempFile.toURI())));

    for (Path path : Files.list(Paths.get(tempDir.toUri().getPath())).collect(Collectors.toList())) {
        String fileName = path.getFileName().toString();

        byte[] encode = Base64.encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(path.toFile()));

        html = html.replaceAll(fileName, "data:image/png;base64,"+ new String(encode));
    }

    return html;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Try something like this : 
byte[] encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64(byteArrayOfImage);
String base64Encoded = new String(encodeBase64);
<img class="img" src="data:image/jpeg;base64," + "base64Encoded">